# Regarding map in scheme

Tags: dictionary, scheme

If I want to use Map on two lists, `lst1` and `lst2`, and I want to apply something with to every element of lst2 using every element of lst1, how would I do that?

For example, if I want to create a list where `(first lst1)` is appended to `(first lst2)... (last lst2)`, and then `(second lst2)` is appended to `(first lst2) ... (last lst2)`. How would I do that?

I tried using maps on two lists.

```
(define (... lst1 lst2)  
  (map (lambda (x y)          
         (if (empty? lst1) empty (cons x (list y))))        
       lst1 lst2))
```

When given the lists `(list 1 2 3)` and `(list 'a 'b 'c)`, I get `(list 1 'a (list 2 'b) (list 3 'c))`. How do I change it so that I get `(list 1 'a (list 1 'b)...`

Thanks!

Edit: sorry for the confusing wording. 
This is what I want given the list `(list 1 2)` and `(list 'a 'b 'c)`:

```
(list 1 'a (list 1 'b) (list 1 'c) (list 2 'a) (list 2 'b) (list 2 'c))
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you want? It sounds like you may want a Cartesian product, not a mapping. If `lst1` is `(list 1 2)` and `lst2` is `(list 'a 'b)`, what do you want the result to be?

Comment: @svk Your intuition turned out to be right, it seems, based on the OP's update.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `(list (list 1 'a) (list 1 'b) ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now the question is clear - you're looking for a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product); try this:

```
(define (cartesian-product lst1 lst2)
  (apply append
         (map (lambda (x)
                (map (lambda (y)
                       (list x y))
                     lst2))
              lst1)))
```

Or if you're using Racket, here's a simpler solution (as suggested by Chris in the comments):

```
(define (cartesian-product lst1 lst2)
  (for*/list ((x lst1) (y lst2))
    (list x y)))
```

For a more general solution, this implementation will work for an arbitrary number of lists:

```
(define (cartesian-product . lsts)
  (foldr (lambda (lst acc)
           (for*/list ((x (in-list lst))
                       (y (in-list acc)))
             (cons x y)))
         '(())
         lsts))
```

Anyway, use it like this:

```
(cartesian-product (list 1 2) (list 'a 'b 'c))
=> '((1 a) (1 b) (1 c) (2 a) (2 b) (2 c))
```

Comment: @user3044487 Is this what you require? the expected output as stated in the question is a bit confusing

Comment: It sounds, from the question update, that all the OP needs is a cartesian product.

Comment: Your Racket implementation of `cartesian-product` is _way_ too complicated. My version is thus: `(define (cartesian-product lst1 lst2)
  (for*/list ((x lst1)
              (y lst2))
    (list x y)))`

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young it's true, but mine works for an arbitray number of lists, replacing `(list lst1 lst2)` with `lsts`

Comment: Fair enough, then. :-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young anyway, you're right, it's two complicated for the simple two-list case. I updated my answer